# DrawManager Draw Polygon, where is the polygon stored?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

When using the "draw polygon" tool from DrawManager, where is the polygon stored once the drawing is completed and it is displayed on the map?

For example, how can I delete this just drawn polygon from the map without creating my own overlay layer and inserting such polygon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The objects created by the DrawingManager aren't stored somewhere where you may access them.

The only way to access them is the `{overlay}complete`-event of the DrawingManager.

e.g. for a polygon:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(event) {
  //event.overlay 
  //is a reference to the polygon, 
  //store it somewhere 
});
```